# Most efficient way to create a film leader animation?

Tags: android, opengl-es, android-animation

I am trying to create an animation of a film leader similar to the one found here: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GfAnyT9QitU. I attempted to do this via frame by frame animation but it is causing out of memory issues in my app. I having been doing some research and I am still wondering what would be a more efficient way of accomplishing something like this. I have been looking into OpenGl but I am not sure if thats overkill for my purposes. What should I be looking into?

Answer (score 0):

It's rarely worth the trouble and resources (as you have discovered) to do such an animation on the device. They are usually done in a PC graphics package / video editor and rendered in a format to play on the device.

Comment: I created the frames for the animation via after effects. Would it be more effective to render out a video instead of frames and just play it on the device?

Comment: Exactly. All the rendering work is done and the device just plays it.